# Using mongo-triggers

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have just installed mongo-triggers via:

```
npm install mongo-triggers
```

I am trying to have a hello world running:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var triggers = require("mongo-triggers");

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', function(err, db) {
  triggers(db.mycollection).insert(function(document, next) {
    console.log("Triggered on insert");
    next();
    });
});
```

I get a:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
```

I am just not very familiar with js so I may have miss sth. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

instead of 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; require("mongo-triggers");

Try 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
var triggers =  require("mongo-triggers");

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just edited my post, but there already was a var triggers = ... in my code. So it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem, here is the full working code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var triggers = require("mongo-triggers");

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', function(err, db) {
  var myCollection = db.collection('mycollection');
  triggers(myCollection).insert(function(document, next) {
    console.log("Triggered on insert");
    next();
  });
});
```

But it has led me to another problem, when I insert sth in the db, on CLI for example with:

```
> use mydatabase
> db.mycollection.insert({"mytest": 1})
```

Nothing is triggered (no print on stdout). I think I am gonna make another post for this one ^^